# Find the period of the sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have a linear transformation $f: \{0,1 \}^n \to\{0,1\}^n$,

$y_1 = x_n, \;  y_2 = x_1 + x_n \bmod 2$, $\;y_3 = x_2, \;...,\; y_n = x_{n-1}$

Find the period of the sequence of sets if $n = 17$ and $\alpha = (1,0,0 ...,0)$:

$$\alpha, \; f(\alpha), \; f(f(\alpha)), \; ... \;$$

I know, that this task can be solved using the theory of linear recurrent. How to solve this another way?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your work regarding the theory of linear recurrent? What is the period that you calculated?

Comment: I found characteristic function $x^{17} + x^{16} + 1$. Then $x^{17} + x^{16} + 1 = (x^{12} + x^{11} + x^8 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(1 + x + x^2)(1 + x^2 + x^3)$ => period = $(2^2 - 1)(2^3 - 1)(2^{12} - 1)$

Comment: Polynomial over a field GF(2)

Comment: I think $f^{(273)}(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Comment: I believe that the characteristic function is $x^{17} - x - 1 = 0$. This makes sense because after 17 transformations, we've completely rotated the columns and added 1 to the diagonal. I also verified it against small cases. $\quad$ We get a similar factorization (EG replacing $ x$ with $1/x$, so the degrees are swapped).    $\quad$ Note that the period of $f$ is a multiple of the period of a specific element, so your calculation is still incomplete.